# NodeJS MongoDB Find posts that are older than current date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

So I have this code line here:

```
let advertisements = await Advertisement.find({created_at: {$lt: moment().valueOf()}});
```

This is what it does:

`created_at`: returns a timestamp when post was created at: 1551198203488.0

`moment.valueOf()` return me a current timestamp for example: 1551198203488.0

Now I need to write this code line that it only finds `ads` that are 1 hour old. Is is possible somehow ?

Also I storing and `group2_date` which store current timestamp BUT with 1 hour added to it like this: `moment().add(1, 'h')`

Comment: Just add `$gt: ...` to your `created_at`. (also, you don't really need the `$lt:` part; any existing document should be older than 0 ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract one hour from the `moment` using `.subtract` function and then use `$gte` operator to obtain only the greater values/documents from the subtracted hours and less then from the current time.

```
let advertisements = await Advertisement.find({
  "created_at": {
    "$lte": moment().toDate(),
    "$gte": moment().subtract(1, 'hours').toDate()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! And now can I somehow make it that advertisements that are 1 hour old should be shown after one hour when they were posted ?

Comment: Yes that's what above query is doing. Isn't it?

Comment: Oof yeah it seems to work. My mistake. I just have user groups who and when can see the posts so I just added the user group to fetch the 1 hour in future ads.

Comment: I just need to add more complexity here with user groups.